# Retrieving Entity from Google App Engine backend to Android App

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I followed the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial) on how to build a backend for mobile devices and was able to create a backend for my Android app and store Entites on GAE.The problem is, i don't know how to retrieve the properties of my entity.To store entites i used the following code:

```
public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

        Userendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Userendpoint.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new JacksonFactory(),
                new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                    public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
                });
        Userendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
                endpointBuilder).build();
        try {
            User user = new User();
            String username;


                  if (responseCheckbox.isChecked()) {

                    username = MainActivity.getPersonName();
                  } 
                  else {
                      username = usernameTextField.getText().toString();
                  }
            String location = locationTextField.getText().toString();
            String tempAge = ageTextField.getText().toString();
            String tempWeight = weightTextField.getText().toString();
            String gender = genderTextField.getText().toString();
            String occupation = occupationTextField.getText().toString();
            int age  = Integer.parseInt(tempAge);
            int weight = Integer.parseInt(tempWeight);


            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setLocation(location);
            user.setAge(age);
            user.setWeight(weight);
            user.setGender(gender);
            user.setOccupation(occupation);

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            User result;
            result = endpoint.insertUser(user).execute();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (long) 0;
    }
}
```

with a  call to `new EndpointsTask().execute(getApplicationContext());` in my `onCreate()` method.

To retrieve the properties of the Entity and display them using `TextViews` this is what i have tried:

```
public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {
protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

    Userendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Userendpoint.Builder(
            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            new JacksonFactory(),
            new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
            });
    Userendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
            endpointBuilder).build();

try {
    User user = new User();
    usernameTextView.setText(user.getUsername());
    locationTextView.setText(user.getLocation());
    ageTextView.setText(user.getAge());
    occupationTextView.setText(user.getOccupation());
    weightTextView.setText(user.getWeight());
    genderTextView.setText(user.getGender());

    User result = endpoint.getUser(user.getUsername()).execute();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return (long) 0;
}}
```

and then called `new EndpointsTask().execute(getApplicationContext());` in my `onCreate()` method.When i tried to run the app, i don't get anything.
I have spent several hours looking for how to do it but i only find tutorials on saving entites.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your user entity source code please ?

Comment: And also your Userendpoint getUser method

Comment: @gomino please find these two [here](https://gist.github.com/JudeOchalifu/9128082)

Comment: Ok so now, are you trying to load all the users, or only one specifically ?

Comment: Am trying to load the user logged into my app.and display the details in the form of a "profile page"

Comment: What kind of authentication method do you use ? do you have the username you want to look for?

Comment: Am using google+.But i gave the user the option of using their Google+ name as username or choose another.This username is then set as the `Id` of the User Entity.If you are familiar with GAE,you can only retrieve an Entity by it's Id

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48010/discussion-between-gomino-and-ojonugwa-ochalifu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to update the ui in a background thread. After retrieving the user from GAE, you should pass it as a result to onPostExecute which get executed on the main thread, and then update your UI there. Here is a quick draft of the change you need in your code to make it work.

```
public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, User> {

   protected User doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

        Userendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Userendpoint.Builder(
            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            new JacksonFactory(),
            new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
            });
        Userendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
            endpointBuilder).build();

        User user = null;
        try {
            user = endpoint.getUser("username").execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return user;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(User user) {
        //update your UI here
        usernameTextView.setText(user.getUsername());
        locationTextView.setText(user.getLocation());
        ageTextView.setText(Integer.toString(user.getAge()));
        occupationTextView.setText(user.getOccupation());
        weightTextView.setText(Integer.toString(user.getWeight()));
        genderTextView.setText(user.getGender());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The line "User user = new User()" should be replaced with " User result = ...". You're creating a new (probably empty) instance of user, which you're using to fill the TextViews. You should use the instance fetched from the server instead.

EDIT: like this: https://gist.github.com/TomTasche/e574b4d98269f6533405

Moreover, it's best practice to do UI stuff in the main thread. So what you should do is return the "User result" and use it in onPostExecuted() to fill your TextView.

Comment: Hi.Am sorry, but it still doesn't work.I should remind you though that the methods `getUsername()`,`getAge()` etc all belong to the `UserEndpoint` class.Could you please explain further how i can create an instance from the server? And the second part? Am pretty new to this.

Comment: Okay, forget about the second part of my answer. It's just best practice and doesn't matter in your case. Here's how I think your code should look like: https://gist.github.com/TomTasche/e574b4d98269f6533405 - don't forget to replace the username at line #14.

Comment: In your example, you use `user.getAge()` etc without creating user.

Comment: lol.Don't you mean `user` to `result`? I figured it out and did just that,no luck.Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: You were right about doing UI stuff in the main thread.Your suggestion on returning user object and using it in the `onPostExecute()` was also spot on.